# Bit flags always including 0 value

Tags: c#, enums, bitflags

So I came accross this code:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options
{
    NA = 0,
    OptionA = 1,
    OptionB = 2,
    OptionC = 4
}
```

Now, technically 'NA' is invalid, if the user doesn't want to select any Options, they just wont select any, and it will get saves to a nullable int. There is no "None" option. However, any time the user selects Options A-C, NA will always get added as well. If I change `NA = 1`, then `OptionC = 8`, everything works well. That portion makes sense. But how come NA will always be included in the user's option list if `NA = 0`?

Edit:

To clear some things up, NA is exclusive, but if I where to select OptionB, then when I view the selected Options, it will show I selected NA and OptionB.

Comment: What do you mean by "NA will always get added as well"?  In what sense?

Comment: @JLRishe: I'm gonna guess that the OP is doing something like `myOpt & Options.NA == Options.NA` which, of course, will always be true. Which is why it doesn't make sense to test for it in the first place. If you want to test `Options.NA`, then you need just `myOpt == Options.NA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're adding `Flags` as an attribute on an enum, and a value that is 0, *it will always be included* if you use `&` to filter the values out.

That is due to that all required bits (none in that case) are always set.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use an enum with the `Flags` attribute, then only use the value of 0 if you have an option that is exclusive of all other options (like `None`, for example). Then you test it with:

```
if (myOptions == Options.Na)
```

Testing with:

```
if ((myOptions & Options.Na) == Options.Na)
```

Will, of course, always return true.

Now the name `Na` suggest that it is exclusive of all the other options, so what's the problem?